# Form css with Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I´m using Flask framework and the library WTforms and I´ve a problem changing the color of each option in the select fields, because it appears always in black instead of in red

I´ve the next form in the **template**

```
    <form method=post class="formulario" action="/rutinas">
          <dl>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.username) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.email) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.sex) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.age) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.type_training) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.days) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.duration) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ render_field(form.intensity) }}
            </div>
          </dl>
            <p><input type=submit class="btn btn-sm btn-default" value=Make></p>
     </form>
```

And in **css** file:

```
input
    {
        color: black;
    }

select option
    {
        color: red;
    }
```

Comment: I´ve forgotten to say that with the input field it works perfectly

Comment: Use your browser to inspect the element. You should be able to see what fields and classes get generated by Flask (to update your selector) and what the computed style is (to figure out what you want to override).

Comment: I´m sorry but I don´t understand, it appears a select field with 3 options, each one of them has a different value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid wrapping the form elements in divs to simplify css selection. This means that:

```
<dl>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ render_field(form.username) }}
    </div>
```

could become:

```
{{form.username(class='css_class'}}
```

with no further divs around. Wtform takes care of rendering that specific field as an input field in the html and Jinja takes care of applying the class you are expressing in the parenthesis.

Useful info in the [WTForms crash course](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/crash_course.html)

From the WTForms crash course:

```
class LoginForm(Form):
    username = TextField('Username')
    password = PasswordField('Password')

form = LoginForm()


<form method="POST" action="/login">
    <div>{{ form.username.label }}: {{ form.username(class="css_class")   }}</div>
    <div>{{ form.password.label }}: {{ form.password() }}</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Simplest answer and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solved it, i´ve written the **css** as:

```
select {
    color: black;
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance:  cover;
}
```

Finally it works if I include the last line, I think it´s because i´m using Bootstrap framework too. Thanks for your answers.